# Help to get Arduino UNO with 4 SoftwareSerial transmit only ports

Tags: arduino-uno

I just started with my Arduino UNO so please pardon my ignorance with SoftwareSerial but I need help. My goal is to make a system of 4 SoftwareSerial ports. Port1 will receive a burst of 5-10 characters and I will then transmit on eventually Port2,3 & 4. Maybe all or just 1 depending on an operator setting. I made the simplest system to try it where I receive on port1 and display on Serial Monitor. All works well until I do a begin to the second port which is commented out in the listing. When it is not commented out it looks like Port1 receives nothing, no display Port1 never says "available" therefore nothing. Any ideas would be most appreciated.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial RotorPort1 (8, 9); //RX, TX
SoftwareSerial RotorPort2 (10, 11);

int RotorPortSpeed = 9600;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
 RotorPort1.begin(RotorPortSpeed);
  //  RotorPort2.begin(RotorPortSpeed);
  delay(200);
 }

void loop() {
 if (RotorPort1.available()) {
    byte incomingByte = RotorPort1.read();
    Serial.print ("data= ");
    Serial.print(incomingByte);
    Serial.print("  ");
    Serial.print(char (incomingByte));
    Serial.println();
    delay (300);

  }
}
```

Comment: read this : https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial

Comment: Do you get any errors when you compile or upload? If you do please share them

Comment: According to online examples like this: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TwoPortReceive suggest you use port.listen()

Comment: Multiple instances may be problematic.  Personally I would be tempted to fork the library (or maybe alt soft serial) and modify it with a method to let you change the transmit pin on the fly; then you could use a single instance and just redirect its output in between messages.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris Stratton suggests, multiple instances of SoftwareSerial may cause issues, particularly with pin-change interrupts.

I adapted SoftwareSerial a while back to have a "send only" version. This can be downloaded from [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/Arduino/SendOnlySoftwareSerial.zip) - 6 KB.

One normal SoftwareSerial and 3 instances of the "send only" may possibly help. I haven't tested it.

---

Chris's suggestion to modify SoftwareSerial to allow pin number changes on-the-fly may be even better. SoftwareSerial can only write to one pin at a time as it blocks, and thus having 4 instances of it doesn't really achieve anything.

---

Another possible approach would be to use a multiplexer chip. I have [a page about that](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11976). You could have a single SoftwareSerial instance, and then use the multiplexer to forward its data to one of (up to 8) pins.

[image: Multiplexer]

You would need pull-up resistors to keep the other pins high (idle) when not in use at a particular moment.

Comment: Thanks for the input. There are no error during compile or upload. I have read all the SoftwareSerial stuff on the Arduino site and it says 2 ports receiving is a NO-NO since there is only 1 buffer but transmit should be OK. I will look at the port listen approach. Will let you know the results. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

IT WORKS!  The solution was to do RotorPort1.listening() right after starting both ports.  Apparently when there are multiple receivers you have to declare which one is the listener but can be changed on the fly.  Nothing in the documentation really said that.
I was almost ready to do the hardware mux since I have been a hardware guy for 30 years and really wanted to do it in software.
You have all been a ton of help.  Thank you. The DJ

Comment: If you are posting this as an answer can you please post the amended code, so it is obvious (to the next person) what is required to make it work? Thanks. (Edit this answer to do that).